# « Nouvels articles » contre « nouveaux articles »

Tags: orthographe, pluriel

Entre « nouvels articles » et « nouveaux articles », quelle expression est la plus juste ?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Le masculin « nouveau » se transforme en « nouvel » pour des raison phonétiques quand il est placé devant un nom commençant par une voyelle, comme par exemple « Le nouvel Observateur ».

Ceci ne s'applique qu'au singulier. En effet, le pluriel « nouveaux » ne pose aucun problème phonétique et reste donc inchangé, comme dans « je me suis fait de nouveaux amis ».

« Nouvels » [n'existe simplement pas](http://www.cnrtl.fr/morphologie/nouvel).

Answer (score 5):

*Article* est un nom masculin, donc « nouveaux articles ». Il n'y a pas de mot *nouvels* : c'est soit *nouveaux* (masculin pluriel), soit *nouvelles* (féminin pluriel).

Comment: Désolé Cyrille je me suis trompé je voulais dire nouvels et ne pas nouvelles, "Question edited"

Comment: `Nouvels` n'existe pas. C'est soit `nouveaux` (masculin pluriel), soit `nouvelles` (féminin pluriel).

Comment: Pourtant ils existent pas mal de gens qui écrivent 'Nouvels'

Comment: Pas en France ! ;)

Comment: Il y a seulement 6200 résultats avec "nouvels articles" sur Google. Donc, c'est faux.

Comment: C'est normal, google ramène tout le vrai et le faux.

Comment: @Cyrille: j'aurais dû ne pas mentionner mon pays dans mon profil, sache bien même les cadres en France font des fautes dans leur langue maternelle http://www.lexpress.fr/actualite/politique/l-hommage-truffe-de-fautes-de-l-elysee-a-danielle-mitterrand_1053746.html.

Comment: @AmiroucheDouda Je n'ai pas été voir de quel pays tu viens, par contre je suis d'accord, même les plus hauts responsables politiques font d'horribles fautes...

Comment: @jcisio:Le fait qu'il y ait 6200 résultats sur google n'est en rien une preuve que ça se dise ou que ça s'écrive. Google n'est pas une référence en matière de correction de la langue (le point discuté ici), tous ces résultats sont des erreurs de celui qui a écrit.
Dans ce nombre il faut déjà éliminer les citations de la même page, le nombre baisse de façon considérable. Ensuite la quasi majorité sont des pluriels de *nouvel article* formés de façon automatique sur des blogs et CMS dont la francisation a été mal faite - par des non francophones.

Comment: @Laure je voulais dire que "nouvels articles" est incorrect en citant Google. C'est clair 6200 résultats contre 18.300.000 résultats de "nouveaux articles". 6200 c'est très très peu. Désolé de vous avoir fait mal entendre.